# Meteor - android much slower than website

Tags: android, performance, meteor, kadira

Hi I'm developing app on meteor which has got browser version and mobile versions. In brief, browser version works well, transition between views/routes is really short, it is really fast. But when I launch app on android (connected to the same DB) there are really long breaks between routes. It can be 1s but on few views it is higher than 5 seconds. In my database there are 3 collections which has got ~2k documents. But this is not the problem for browser version, there is only problem on android.

I tested it with Kadira. I can't see what is going on while routing but for example there is enormous difference in login method. In browser it takes maybe 15ms, on Android it is 400ms.

And what is weird (and probably the most important): in browser in the end there is only observeChanges on user collection. In Android there are ALL observeChanges on every collection and it takes a lot of time.

Of course I will try to optimize current algorithm but probably it is not the problem because browser version runs well.

Comment: What kind of device are you running it on and what os version is it?